# 3des authentication no response

Tags: authentication, mifare, 3des

I send the command 1A:00 to the Mifare Ultralight C tag by using APDU command 
Here is the log:

`inList passive target
write:  4A 1 0
read:   4B 1 1 0 44 0 7 4 C2 35 CA 2C 2C 80
write:  40 1 1A 0`

I don't know why when I send 1A 00, it did not respond with RndA? 
My code is this: 
`bool success = nfc.inListPassiveTarget();
    if (success) {
    uint8_t auth_apdu[] = {
        0x1A, 
        0x00
    };
    uint8_t response[255];
    uint8_t responseLength = 255;
    success = nfc.inDataExchange(auth_apdu, sizeof(auth_apdu), response, &responseLength);
    if (success) {
      Serial.println("\n Successfully sent 1st auth_apdu \n");
      Serial.println("\n The response is: \n");
      nfc.PrintHexChar(response, responseLength);
        }` 
When I try to read pages with command 0x30, , it works OK, but not the authentication command: 1A:00 
I don't know what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Is this the whole log you get or is there one more `read:` entry afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that I should use `inCommunicateThru` ( 0x42 ) instead of `inDataExchange`  ( 0x40 ).
Thus the correct command should be : `0x42 1A 0`